# Permanently translate a binary for a different architecture?

Tags: arm, qemu, binary

I use an ARM machine, so I'm always digging around for this sort of thing.

I've been told that `qemu` translates processor instructions "on the fly". Hewever, on a Raspberry Pi, this is slow and frustrating. Is there any miracle way to do this more permanently and actually generate an ARM binary independent of any translator?

Comment: get source code, compiler, and do cross-compiling for ARM

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are a few ways to do so. One is to get the source-code of the program and translate it (compile it) for ARM. You could do this on an ARM environment or via cross-compiler.
The second way is to find a repository with already translated (compiled) Versions of the program and install the program from the repository.

Comment: What if the software is closed-source and the authors won't respond to my pleading?

Comment: This is only possible if the design is like (for example) java VM. You can't to "re-translation" from one processor architecture to another in that static way. qemu and other virtual VMs do more then "stupid" translation of cpu instructions. this all is working cause of a run-time environment.

Comment: Yeah. I asked this question pretty hopefully and optimistically.